# Force client hostname when proxying https

Tags: go, proxy, ssl-certificate

I'm using toxiproxy. I'm having [this exact issue](https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy/issues/175). Both of the `curl` solutions mentioned in the issue work ([solution a](https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy/issues/175#issue-225301786), [solution b](https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy/issues/175#issuecomment-303372210)), but I can't use curl. I need to use the go standard `net/http` library.

Is there any way to use `net/http` in such a fashion that I can explicitly tell it what host the proxy is using so it can see that the certificate is valid?

I've tried setting `Host` and `Authority` headers on the net/http.Request, but that didn't work.

**Details**

Toxiproxy output:

> proxy=[::]:22002 upstream=maps.googleapis.com:443

My code:

```
url := "https://localhost:22002/maps/api/geocode/json..."
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
req.Host = "maps.googleapis.com"
req.Header.Set("Host", "maps.googleapis.com")
res, err := httpClient.Do(req)
```

Error:

> x509: certificate is valid for *.googleapis.com,
>   *.clients6.google.com, *.cloudendpointsapis.com, cloudendpointsapis.com, googleapis.com, not localhost

Comment: I've updated to show Host is being set in two different ways, though I think I've tried both separately and they each gave that error ultimately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `http.Request.Host` field so that the http request has the correct header

```
req.Host = "maps.googleapis.com"
```

An you also need to set the hostname in the `tls.Config.ServerName` field for SNI and host name verification.

If you've already configured a transport for your `httpClient`, you can set it like so:

```
httpClient.Transport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{
    ServerName: "maps.googleapis.com",
}
```

Or for small programs you can override the default:

```
http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{
    ServerName: "maps.googleapis.com",
}
```

Or create a custom transport for your program

```
var httpTransport = &http.Transport{
    Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
    DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
        KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
        DualStack: true,
    }).DialContext,
    MaxIdleConns:          100,
    IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
    TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
    ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
        ServerName: "maps.googleapis.com",
    },
}
```

Just make sure you reuse the Transport, and don't create a new one for each request.

Comment: I've tried to do as you show: `httpClient.Transport = &http.Transport{ TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{ ServerName: "maps.googleapis.com",},}` Is this the change you suggested? Now I get a 404. (If I change the authority in the url to be the non-proxy maps.googleapis.com, I get 200 with real results.) I think the reason I'm getting a 404 is that it's resolving to googleapis.com instead of maps.googleapis.com

Comment: Did you set the request Host field to “maps.googleapis.com” too?

Comment: No. Was I supposed to set Host in addition to Tls server name?

Comment: Yes, you need both. Since you’re adding a new Transport here, you should make sure to complete the rest of the recommended settings, but make sure you reuse the same transport and don’t re-add it each time. See the DefaultTransport for example.

Comment: With TLS enabled, the HTTP header is encrypted. The server has to pick a certificate for decryption before it can inspect the Host header. That's what the ServerName field is for; it is sent as part of the TLS handshake (that is called [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)). After decrypting the HTTP header the server looks at the Host header to route the request to the correct virtual host. That's why you need to set both values.

Comment: @Peter: Yes exactly. I misremembered the Transport setting ServerName from the request. It's not hard to implement now, but it's a breaking change so I don't think it could be done with go1.